# Who owns and operates monero.org?

Tags: getmonero-website

Who owns and operates [monero.org](http://monero.org/)?

Has there been any attempt by the Monero core team to gain control of that domain name?  Has there been any evidence of malicious behavior from its owner or operator so far? Was [getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org/) chosen as the official domain only because [monero.org](http://monero.org/) was already registered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [core team](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) chose getmonero.org as the best available domain at the time because the owner of monero.org never self identified or otherwise communicated with the core team. According to well known Monero community member [Gingeropolous](https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/2363/difference-between-getmonero-org-and-monero-org):

> monero.org is owned and operated by an unknown party. They are apparently not part of the community because they haven't spoken up. Monero.org has been benign up to this point, but I wouldn't download anything from that site. My level of distrust stems from the fact that the cryptonote environment is relatively hostile (IMO, no one else could have performed the 201623 attack and, in general, the overall scam is hostile to the entire crypto community)

Based on the above should be no surprise that the domain registration is [anonymous](https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=monero.org)

> Raw WHOIS Record
>   Domain Name: MONERO.ORG
>   Domain ID: D169443173-LROR
>   WHOIS Server:
>   Referral URL: http://www.godaddy.com
>   Updated Date: 2016-07-20T16:33:55Z
>   Creation Date: 2013-08-15T21:54:22Z
>   Registry Expiry Date: 2017-08-15T21:54:22Z
>   Sponsoring Registrar: GoDaddy.com, LLC
>   Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 146
>   Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
>   Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
>   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
>   Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
>   Registrant ID: CR175374311
>   Registrant Name: Registration Private
>   Registrant Organization: Domains By Proxy, LLC
>   Registrant Street: DomainsByProxy.com
>   Registrant Street: 14747 N Northsight Blvd Suite 111, PMB 309
>   Registrant City: Scottsdale
>   Registrant State/Province: Arizona
>   Registrant Postal Code: 85260
>   Registrant Country: US
>   Registrant Phone: +1.4806242599
>   Registrant Phone Ext:
>   Registrant Fax: +1.4806242598
>   Registrant Fax Ext:
>   Registrant Email: MONERO.ORG@domainsbyproxy.com
>   Admin ID: CR175374312
>   Admin Name: Registration Private
>   Admin Organization: Domains By Proxy, LLC
>   Admin Street: DomainsByProxy.com
>   Admin Street: 14747 N Northsight Blvd Suite 111, PMB 309
>   Admin City: Scottsdale
>   Admin State/Province: Arizona
>   Admin Postal Code: 85260
>   Admin Country: US
>   Admin Phone: +1.4806242599
>   Admin Phone Ext:
>   Admin Fax: +1.4806242598
>   Admin Fax Ext:
>   Admin Email: MONERO.ORG@domainsbyproxy.com
>   Tech ID: CR175374314
>   Tech Name: Registration Private
>   Tech Organization: Domains By Proxy, LLC
>   Tech Street: DomainsByProxy.com
>   Tech Street: 14747 N Northsight Blvd Suite 111, PMB 309
>   Tech City: Scottsdale
>   Tech State/Province: Arizona
>   Tech Postal Code: 85260
>   Tech Country: US
>   Tech Phone: +1.4806242599
>   Tech Phone Ext:
>   Tech Fax: +1.4806242598
>   Tech Fax Ext:
>   Tech Email: MONERO.ORG@domainsbyproxy.com
>   Name Server: NS71.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
>   Name Server: NS72.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
>   DNSSEC: unsigned
>
> > > Last update of WHOIS database: 2016-08-25T05:35:08Z <<<